# How to count gproc registered processes?

Tags: erlang

I have a bunch of processed registered by gproc, and I want to count these processes any time I'd have to. Of course, if every process works fine, it wouldn't be a problem. I can just use counters incrementing and decrementing them every time the process is started or stopped.

But the problem is, processes do not always act fine. Sometimes they just go dead for some unobvious reason. It's ok by design, except I still want to know an exact number of processes still running.

Is there a nice way to count processes, which are active just now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the processes you register in gproc are supervised you could just use `count_children` from [supervisor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#count_children-1). You could for example register a new process with gproc inside the `init` of a `gen_server` and unregister its `terminate`. You would get the benefits of gproc and supervision at the same time.

If you are not using supervision you could use gproc counters (or aggregate_counter?, see gproc api).